# Download a large file with ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to download a large file with ansible (10 GB). Depending on the connection this takes half an hour and fails often with unarchive or get_url.

How can I achieve this ideally with resuming in case of error and a kind of progress?

Comment: According to this [source](https://ilovesymposia.com/2013/04/11/automatically-resume-interrupted-downloads-in-osx-with-curl/) the following command can be used with shell: export ec=18; while [ $ec -eq 18 ]; do /usr/bin/curl -O -C - "http://www.example.com/a-big-archive.zip"; export ec=$?; done

Comment: But still need something to show the progress.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to get a progress inside a task in Ansible.
You could manually download in multiple chunks by using the `command` module to launch `curl` with a `--range` option in a [`with_sequence` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-integer-sequences), it will be kind of a progress display.
(You can also use the `uri` module with `method: HEAD` to get the file size to compute the ranges to use in the loop for the curl call)

To resume in case of error, there is the [do-until loop syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_loops.html#do-until-loops).

Answer (score 2):

you can use the `async` for this, in the below example, we are downloading a big file using `get_url` along with `async` option and then waiting on the download job to finish using `async_status` module

```
 - name: Get the tar file from the repo
    get_url:
      url: "{{ hdf_patch_repo_url }}/{{ hdf_tar_name }}"
      dest: "{{ hdf_patch_local_path }}/{{ hdf_tar_name }}"
      owner: xxxx
      group: xxxx
      mode: 0755
    async: 6000
    poll: 0
    register: hdf_patch_download_result

  - name: check status of HDF tar file download
    async_status:
      jid: "{{ hdf_patch_download_result.ansible_job_id }}"
    register: hdf_patch_download_job_result
    until: hdf_patch_download_job_result.finished
    retries: 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the command module with wget and its '--continue' argument to resume downloading a partially downloaded file, and put a number of retries on the task ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually rasing `time_out` value do the trick in get_url.
Try rasing it to 1800 seconds.

If it won't work i suggest splitting the file into chunks using archiving program (I use 7Zip - [7-zip-split-archive](http://www.newsgroupreviews.com/7-zip-split-archive.html))

Comment: 1. I can't influence the size of the file. Just raising the timeout won't let me resume it in case it fails. A progress is also not shown with get_url. So this answer doesn't meet my needs from the question.